# PIL Python Image Text "IOError: cannot find glyph data file"

Tags: python, image, fonts, python-imaging-library

I have been making an image reconition system, and I want each frame to show on it what the computer sees. I got the hard part done, and basically my question is how do I put text on a JPG file? I tried a LOT of methods, and I keep getting this error. I found that PIL gets me the closest to what I want.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 67, in <module>
    font = ImageFont.truetype(ImageFont.load(font_), z)
  File "C:\Users\techt\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 211, in load
    f._load_pilfont(filename)
  File "C:\Users\techt\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 76, in _load_pilfont
    raise IOError("cannot find glyph data file")
IOError: cannot find glyph data file
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to `ImageFont.load()` the font first. Just directly pass the path or file to `ImageFont.truetype()`. `ImageFont.load()` tries to load a **bitmap** font.